# Data not received in firebase until I submit an empty form-javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, forms

How can I make the data reach firebase as soon as I fill out the form without the need to submit an empty form before?

I have been stuck and I searched and asked chatGPT yet I still wasn't able to find an answer, whenever I submit the form nothing reaches me on firebase, but if I submit an empty form and then refill it I will find the data in firebase and if I submit data on an other day all the previous data in firebase gets deleted. I also have another page that I want to be redirected to which is also a form so can someone help me out.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Carma Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./page2.css">
    <script defer src="./page2.js">
</script>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo"></div>
          <h1>carma</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <form id="form" action="./page3.html" method="GET">
        
            <div class="input-control" id="all">
                <label for="firstname" class="heading">First Name</label>
                <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-control" id="all">
                <label for="lastname" class="heading">Last Name</label>
                <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-control" id="all">
                <label for="email" class="heading">Email</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-control" id="all">
                <label for="tely" class="heading">Phone Number</label>
                <input id="tely" name="tely" type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number">
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>

            <button id="btn" class="Start-btn" type="submit" value="submit">Next</button>
        </form>
        
    </div> 

    <script type="module">
        // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
        import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.0/firebase-app.js";
        import {getDatabase, ref, set, get, child} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.0/firebase-database.js";
        
        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyCakSDaxLlVQiktO7Zl0-yMoyUYzSTkvVI",
  authDomain: "carma-deb8c.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://carma-deb8c-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "carma-deb8c",
  storageBucket: "carma-deb8c.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "813352209104",
  appId: "1:813352209104:web:21154ee30add3d19916cd5"
    };
      
        // Initialize Firebase
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    
    
        // get ref to database services
        const db = getDatabase(app);
    
        document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', function(e){
            form.addEventListener('submit', e =>{
    
    validateInputs();
    
    console.log(isFormValid());
    if(isFormValid()==true){
        form.submit() ;
        alert("thanks");
     }else {
         e.preventDefault();
         alert("Please fill out the form correctly.");
     }
    
    });
    
            set(ref(db, 'information/' + document.getElementById("firstname").value),
            {
                FirstName: document.getElementById("firstname").value,
                LastName: document.getElementById("lastname").value,
                Email: document.getElementById("email").value,
                PhoneNumber: document.getElementById("tely").value
            });
            
        })
      </script>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
const lastname = document.getElementById('lastname');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const tely = document.getElementById('tely');

form.addEventListener('submit', e =>{
    
    validateInputs();

    console.log(isFormValid());
    if(isFormValid()==true){
        form.submit() ;
     }else {
         e.preventDefault();
     }

});

function isFormValid(){
    const inputContainers = form.querySelectorAll('.input-control');
    let result = true;
    inputContainers.forEach((container)=>{
        if(container.classList.contains('error')){
            result = false;
        }
    });
    return result;
}

const setError = (element, message) => {
    const inputControl = element.parentElement;
    const errorDisplay = inputControl.querySelector('.error');

    errorDisplay.innerText = message;
    inputControl.classList.add('error');
    inputControl.classList.remove('success')
}

const setSuccess = element => {
    const inputControl = element.parentElement;
    const errorDisplay = inputControl.querySelector('.error');

    errorDisplay.innerText = '';
    inputControl.classList.add('success');
    inputControl.classList.remove('error');
};

const isValidEmail = email => {
    const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}

const isValidPhone = tely => {
    const phone = /^(009665|9665|\+9665|05|5)(5|0|3|6|4|9|1|8|7)([0-9]{7})$/;
    return phone.test(tely);
}

const validateInputs = () => {
    const firstnameValue = firstname.value.trim();
    const lastnameValue = lastname.value.trim();
    const emailValue = email.value.trim();
    const telyValue = tely.value.trim();

    

    if(firstnameValue === '') {
        setError(firstname, 'First Name is required');
    } else {
        setSuccess(firstname);
    }

    if(emailValue === '') {
        setError(email, 'Email is required');
    } else if (!isValidEmail(emailValue)) {
        setError(email, 'Provide a valid Email address');
    } else {
        setSuccess(email);
    }

    if(lastnameValue === '') {
        setError(lastname, 'Last Name is required');
    }else {
        setSuccess(lastname);
    }

    if(telyValue === '') {
        setError(tely, 'Phone Number is required');
    } else if (!isValidPhone(telyValue)) {
        setError(tely, 'Phone Number must be of 10 characters');
    } else {
        setSuccess(tely);
    }

};
```

How can I make the data reach firebase as soon as I fill out the form without the need to submit an empty form before?

I have been stuck and I searched and asked chatGPT yet I still wasn't able to find an answer, whenever I submit the form nothing reaches me on firebase, but if I submit an empty form and then refill it I will find the data in firebase and if I submit data on an other day all the previous data in firebase gets deleted. I also have another page that I want to be redirected to which is also a form so can someone help me out.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Carma Form</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./page2.css">
    <script defer src="./page2.js">
</script>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="logo"></div>
          <h1>carma</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <form id="form" action="./page3.html" method="GET">
        
            <div class="input-control" id="all">
                <label for="firstname" class="heading">First Name</label>
                <input id="firstname" name="firstname" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-control" id="all">
                <label for="lastname" class="heading">Last Name</label>
                <input id="lastname" name="lastname" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-control" id="all">
                <label for="email" class="heading">Email</label>
                <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="input-control" id="all">
                <label for="tely" class="heading">Phone Number</label>
                <input id="tely" name="tely" type="tel" placeholder="Phone Number">
                <div class="error"></div>
            </div>

            <button id="btn" class="Start-btn" type="submit" value="submit">Next</button>
        </form>
        
    </div> 

    <script type="module">
        // Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
        import { initializeApp } from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.0/firebase-app.js";
        import {getDatabase, ref, set, get, child} from "https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.5.0/firebase-database.js";
        
        // Your web app's Firebase configuration
        const firebaseConfig = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyCakSDaxLlVQiktO7Zl0-yMoyUYzSTkvVI",
  authDomain: "carma-deb8c.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://carma-deb8c-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "carma-deb8c",
  storageBucket: "carma-deb8c.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "813352209104",
  appId: "1:813352209104:web:21154ee30add3d19916cd5"
    };
      
        // Initialize Firebase
        const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    
    
        // get ref to database services
        const db = getDatabase(app);
    
        document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener('click', function(e){
            form.addEventListener('submit', e =>{
    
    validateInputs();
    
    console.log(isFormValid());
    if(isFormValid()==true){
        form.submit() ;
        alert("thanks");
     }else {
         e.preventDefault();
         alert("Please fill out the form correctly.");
     }
    
    });
    
            set(ref(db, 'information/' + document.getElementById("firstname").value),
            {
                FirstName: document.getElementById("firstname").value,
                LastName: document.getElementById("lastname").value,
                Email: document.getElementById("email").value,
                PhoneNumber: document.getElementById("tely").value
            });
            
        })
      </script>
    

</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
const form = document.getElementById('form');
const firstname = document.getElementById('firstname');
const lastname = document.getElementById('lastname');
const email = document.getElementById('email');
const tely = document.getElementById('tely');

form.addEventListener('submit', e =>{
    
    validateInputs();

    console.log(isFormValid());
    if(isFormValid()==true){
        form.submit() ;
     }else {
         e.preventDefault();
     }

});

function isFormValid(){
    const inputContainers = form.querySelectorAll('.input-control');
    let result = true;
    inputContainers.forEach((container)=>{
        if(container.classList.contains('error')){
            result = false;
        }
    });
    return result;
}

const setError = (element, message) => {
    const inputControl = element.parentElement;
    const errorDisplay = inputControl.querySelector('.error');

    errorDisplay.innerText = message;
    inputControl.classList.add('error');
    inputControl.classList.remove('success')
}

const setSuccess = element => {
    const inputControl = element.parentElement;
    const errorDisplay = inputControl.querySelector('.error');

    errorDisplay.innerText = '';
    inputControl.classList.add('success');
    inputControl.classList.remove('error');
};

const isValidEmail = email => {
    const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}

const isValidPhone = tely => {
    const phone = /^(009665|9665|\+9665|05|5)(5|0|3|6|4|9|1|8|7)([0-9]{7})$/;
    return phone.test(tely);
}

const validateInputs = () => {
    const firstnameValue = firstname.value.trim();
    const lastnameValue = lastname.value.trim();
    const emailValue = email.value.trim();
    const telyValue = tely.value.trim();

    

    if(firstnameValue === '') {
        setError(firstname, 'First Name is required');
    } else {
        setSuccess(firstname);
    }

    if(emailValue === '') {
        setError(email, 'Email is required');
    } else if (!isValidEmail(emailValue)) {
        setError(email, 'Provide a valid Email address');
    } else {
        setSuccess(email);
    }

    if(lastnameValue === '') {
        setError(lastname, 'Last Name is required');
    }else {
        setSuccess(lastname);
    }

    if(telyValue === '') {
        setError(tely, 'Phone Number is required');
    } else if (!isValidPhone(telyValue)) {
        setError(tely, 'Phone Number must be of 10 characters');
    } else {
        setSuccess(tely);
    }

};
```